# Include Controller (executing all the simple controllers in the test fragment)

Tags: jmeter

[main-sub projects][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YL97.jpg

As shown in the picture, I've created two JMeter projects (**Main. JMX, Sub1.JMX**). The main.JMX has a thread group (**Subscription**) that has include controller to run the **Sub1.jmx** project.

**Sub1.JMX** is created with a Thread Group (**Subscription**) and **Test Fragment**. All the reusable functionalities are added under the test fragment such as **Sub1-Login, Sub1-Logout, and Sub1-close** using the simple controllers. A test case (**Test Case-1**) is created under the thread group **Subscription** that is invoking **Sub1-Login, Sub1-Logout** simple controllers using module controller. The **Sub1-close** simple controller is not used in the test case.

When I run the Main.JMX, is executing the test case (Test Case-1), which includes login and logout and also remaining simple controllers from the test fragment (**Sub1-close**).

what is the best way to run only simple controllers (*defined in the test fragment*) referenced in the test cases?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) runs a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment). **Entire**.

If you don't want to run a certain part of the test fragment you have 2 options:

1. Either put it under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and come up with a JMeter Function or Variable which will control whether it will be executed now or not
2. Or split your Test Fragment into 2 (or more) separate fragments and compose your "test case" from smaller parts .